# Conditional formatting (exact criteria and multiple columns)

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I'm an excel vba noob and I'm quite stuck at this code wherein I need to format cells containing a specific criteria for multiple columns.

For example I would need to highlight all values except the cells which contains "Complete" into YELLOW with BOLD RED FONT.

I've tried to just record it by simply filtering out "Complete" and highlighting all other values but I would need it to be dynamic.

```
Sub Macro1()

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$6114").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
    "=Incomplete", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
Range("F171").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range("F171:F6114").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.Font
    .Color = -16776961
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

Will be grateful for any assistance!

Comment: Using a `For` loop to iterate through each cell in column `F` would do you great! :)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Have you tried recording a macro?

Comment: I've tried recording it but the issue I had was it wasn't dynamic enough if in case more data would be added to what I currently have. One of the solutions I came up with is to create a dynamic range first in vb then doing the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

With rng

.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>Complete", Operator:=xlAnd

End With

With rng.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(rng.Rows.Count, 6)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    With .Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = vbYellow
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    With .Font
        .Color = vbRed
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Bold = True
    End With

End With

End Sub
```